# Conditional formatting (red text) in Oracle Apex SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Using Oracle APEX, I am working with Salary data. I would like to make all salaries `>= $100,000.00` display with red text. How can I do this directly in my code?

Table name is `OEHR_EMPLOYEE` and Column name is `Salary`

Answer (score 5):

In query? Something like this:

```
select case when salary >= 100000 then '<span style="color:red">' || to_char(salary) || '</span>'
            else to_char(salary)
       end as salary
from oehr_employee
where ...
```

Don't forget to set column's "escape special characters" property to "No".

Example (a classic report) created on Scott's EMP table (I painted salaries higher than 2000):

[image]

---

Additionally, it is an interactive report, go to Actions button and conditionally paint salaries higher than 100.000 - it is easier, and even end users can modify it if they want to.

Comment: This answer made the text display as, for example <span style="color:red">$100,800.00</span> instead of displaying $100,800.00 in red

Comment: Probably, because you don't read the whole post and you didn't **set column's "escape special characters" property to "No"**. I attached an image which shows that it *works*.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  empno,
        fname,
        case 
            when sal >= 100000 then '<span style="color:red">'||sal||'</span>'
            else sal
        end as salary
from emp
```

> Going to Salary Column > Security > Escape special charactters : No